# How to create Source(XML) to Target(SQL Server Tables) mapping document

Tags: xml

I have to create a S2T (Source to Target) mapping document.  The source will be XML and the target is SQL Server tables.  I have done S2T mapping documents which the source and target are database tables but never from XML to database tables.  Would anyone happen to have an Excel template or any kind of template so I can start with?  Any links or and advice would be great.

Thanks.